# Removing unconnected nodes from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, tree

I'm working on a tree structure with company hierarchy. All the data is stored in a SQL Server database.

The database has two columns with ID and parent node ID (both are *varchar(5)*).

Now, when i remove a node, all of the node's children (and their children) will be left in the database - unconnected. How am i supposed to remove these?

EDIT: I'm using https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18378/Organization-Chart-Generator to generate the chart.

Comment: I understand you are trying to store a tree structure in a one table DB. Better approach could be to have more tables with according foreign keys between parent and child nodes. What is the exact tree structure? Is it a B-tree? what is the height of your tree?

Comment: it sounds like you have no foreign keys setup in this table, and therefore you are able to corrupt the table by removing parents. I would start by fixing the design and setup the proper foreign keys.

Comment: You are going to have to create a recursive query (using a CTE) that will get all he children, then delete from the deepest node first, finally deleting the final node.

Comment: @GuidoG I forgot to mention i also have another, PRIMARY IDENTITY (1, 1) id column - just thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: @apomene I'm not exactly sure what the exact structure is. Parent nodes can have unlimited number of children and i'm only storing data about node's parents. Also, the max height of the tree is 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no foreign keys, this will do it. I'm creating a sample table called nodes with two columns, ID and Parent. They are integers in my version but that doesn't matter.

```
create table nodes(id int, parent int)
insert nodes values (1,null),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,null)

select * from nodes
```

Result is:

```
id  parent
1   NULL
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   NULL
```

Create a CTE that traverses the relationships

```
declare @target int; set @target=2
;with cte as 
(
select *, 1 as depth from nodes where id=@target
union all
select nodes.*, depth+1 from nodes
join cte on cte.id=nodes.parent
)
delete nodes where id in (select id from cte)
```

This is the result

```
select * from nodes

1   NULL
3   1
5   NULL
```

If you have foreign keys then you will need to look through this from the highest depth to the lowest to avoid errors. This will do it (without a cursor)

```
declare @temp table(id int, depth int)

declare @target int; set @target=2
;with cte as 
(
select *, 1 as depth from nodes where id=@target
union all
select nodes.*, depth+1 from nodes
join cte on cte.id=nodes.parent
)
insert @temp 
select id,depth from cte

while exists(select * from @temp)
begin
    delete nodes from nodes
    join @temp t on t.id=nodes.id
    where depth=(select max(depth) from @temp)

    delete @temp where depth=(select max(depth) from @temp)
end
```

Result is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need 2 things here,

- First you need a system that prevents from removing a master that has
  childs.
- Second you need a procedure for removing a master with all its childs.

The first is necessary so nobody can remove a master by using any other means then the correct procedure.

Here is an example of how you can setup such a system

```
create table test (
  id int not null identity,
  name varchar(10),
  parentid int  null,

  constraint pk_id primary key (id),  
  constraint fk_pid foreign key (parentid) references test (id) 
)

insert into test (name, parentid) 
values ('master', null), ('child1', 1), ('child2', 1), ('child3', 3)
```

now when you delete for example the first row (name=master) then sql server will stop you, and return an error saying that the foreign key `fk_pid` is violated.
In other words, nobody can remove a master anymore as long it still has childs.

Now for a procedure that can remove a master with all his children, you can look at the other answers and just pick the one you like best.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a recursive procedure: recursively removing first all the childs of a node, and then deleting that node.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETE_NODE
  @NODE_ID int
AS
BEGIN
  declare @CHILD_NODE_ID int;    
  declare CHILDS cursor for select NODE_ID from MY_TABLE where PARENT_NODE_ID = @NODE_ID;

  open CHILDS;
  fetch next from CHILDS into @CHILD_NODE_ID;
  while @@fetch_status = 0 
  begin  
    exec DELETE_NODE @NODE_ID = @CHILD_NODE_ID;

    fetch next from CHILDS into @CHILD_NODE_ID;
  end
  close CHILDS;
  deallocate CHILDS;

  delete from MY_TABLE where NODE_ID = @NODE_ID
END
GO
```

By the way, you should add a relationship (foreign key) on your table with itself for the fields PARENT_NODE_ID and NODE_ID, so you can't remove nodes leaving children unconnected.